# React History Hook Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

React Hook "useHistory" is called in function "header" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

## Below Is My Code

```
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
function header() {
    let history = useHistory()
    return (
        <header>
            <div className="header_buttons">
                <Link onClick={history.push('/auth/login')} to='/auth/login'>
                    <a href="" className='primary-link'>Login</a>
                </Link>
            </div>
        </header>
    )}
export default header
```

## Below Is The Error I'm Getting

```
Failed to compile.

./src/Header/header.js
  Line 6:19:  React Hook "useHistory" is called in function "header" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React components have to be capitalized. Rename it to `Header`.

```
function Header() {
   let history = useHistory();

   return (...);
}
```